# Ahranov-Bohm problem for a 1D ring solenoid of radius $R_0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, aharonov-bohm

In order to solve the problem above, I'm trying to write the vector potential of a 1D ring solenoid of radius $R_0$, with a magnetic field $\vec{B}=B_0 \hat{\phi}$ which is constant along the circle. This is a rough approximation of a toroidal solenoid such that used in the Tonomura experiment.  Applying the Stokes theorem it is easy to show that
$A_{\theta}=\frac{\Phi_0}{2\pi r} \hat{\theta }$ once that the following coordinates $(\phi, \theta, r) $ are introduced:
$$x=(R_0+rcos\theta)cos\phi;\quad y=(R_0+rcos\theta)sin\phi; \quad z=rsin\theta.$$ My question arises because I want to solve explicitely the Schrodinger equation for the system of an electron coming from infinity along the z-axis. Now I'm wondering if this system of coordinate is suitable in order to find an explicit solution to reproduce the pattern of interference seen in the Tonomura experiment.

Comment: It might be better to use [this version of toroidal coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ToroidalCoordinates.html).  These avoid the singularities & double-counting that you would get in your coordinates when $r \cos \theta + R_0 \leq 0$ .

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know this type of coordinates.

Comment: Anyway, I 've just noticed that in this paper "https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/220107937.pdf", the author  used oblate spheroidal coordinate, claiming that in this way the laplacian is separable, so I'm pretty confused on which system of coordinate to use.